# Is there a way to push stock ticker from tradingview to Python?

Tags: python, stock, tradingview-api

Is there a way to push a stock's ticker from tradingview to Python? So, when a user enters a ticker on the chart, the ticker gets automatically sent to a python code? (external). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview sends alerts via [Webhook](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000529348-about-webhooks/)

You will find many examples on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=tradingview%20webhook&type=repositories)

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I don't want to use alerts. I want to use indicators; alerts must be activated on every stock. However, what I want to do is to be able to get the ticker selected by the user as soon as they put it on the chart without alerts.